# Two different modals checking with one function

Tags: jquery, function, modal-dialog

I am looking to have multiple modals on my site as follows:

1. The first modal will have general information for them to login/register and I will need to display that if a user is anonymous (not logged in) or does not have an active subscription (even if they're logged in). I already have a flag/check for this.
2. The other modals will house YouTube videos...

When a user clicks on the play buttons in a grid, I would like to call one function to check the flag I was speaking of. If the flag is true, then the appropriate modal will popup for that particular video. If the flag is false, then the login/register modal will popup.

How can I go about doing something like this and can someone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this. As you said if flag is TRUE then trigger the second function so it's pretty simple you just need to use `IF ELSE` statement.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").on("click",function(){
      //Your first module code goes here.
      alert('I am first.');
      secondModule();
  });
});
function secondModule(){
  //Your second module code goes here.
  alert('I am second');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Zaid! But I am going to have multiple buttons or links to click. A page could have 6,7,8 or 20 videos on it, so that means just as many Play links. When they click on the Play link, I want to run this check and dynamically display the appropriate video in the modal.

Comment: Then assign unique ID to each `btn` and use this kind of code within the loop. So that every video has it's on script.

Comment: I could have multiple DIVs with the video in it, but I need those to pop-up in a modal.

Comment: I see. That's a lot of scripts.

Comment: I don't have it written yet. Just trying to see how easy/hard it would be.

Comment: This is the insecure way to do it. It will do the job , but if login is important, expect it to be bypassed.

Comment: What about keeping two DIVs as the modals and in the video DIV, passing the video URL dynamically from the onClick event on the Play button? How could I go about doing that?

Comment: I have no idea about your `DOM` structure. Ideally, you should create separate models and handle by using Ajax. If the user is authenticated by ajax request trigger first model else trigger second.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a little security issue with this. If it's 100% client side, it will be easy to bypass just using the console, so I'd suggest an ajax call to your flag, then return the appropriate html. The cool thing about that is you'll be able to reuse this all over the site.

[EDIT: Evidently, you need to pass a variable for the video, the script has been updated to reflect that.]

In short, in your HTML, add a class named "checkLoggedIn" ( or anything) to the links that will launch the modal...

```
<a href="a-script-that-handles-non-js-requests.php" data-videoID="somevideoID" class="checkLoggedIn">View my rad videos!</a>
```

Then the modal (assuming bootstrap here)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="videoModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
     </div>
         <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

Then in your ready func...

```
$(function() {
$('#videoModal').modal();
    $(".checkLoggedIn").click(function( event ) {
       event.preventDefault();
let videoID = $(this).data('videoID');
         $.get( "check_login.php?videoID="+videoID, function( data ) {
             $( ".modal-body" ).html( data );
              $('#.videoModal').modal('show'); 
                //show right now with .modal-body containing the returned 
                //HTML from the check_login.php script.
         });
     });

});
```

So, onload, any element classed with "checkLoggedIn" will be prevented from doing anything clickable. An ajax call to a server side script called "check_login.php" will fire, that script will return the HTML for either your login or your videos.

The wrong way to do it would be some kind of "if" statement to decide if the dude's logged in or not. then show the modal.

[EDIT: Your php script has to do a little more with the videoID]

```
<?php 
if(dudeIsLoggedIn()){
    $html = goGetTheHTMLForThisVideo($_GET['videoID']);
    if($html){
       echo $html;
     } else {
       echo "Sorry, the video isn't available";
     }
} else { // dude isn't logged in
    echo goGetTheHTMLForLoggingIn();
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Lucas! So, with multiple play buttons, how will the modal know which video to play? It's a list of videos, each having a play button. The video modal/DIV needs to know which URL to play, but at the same time, check that flag if the user has an active account.

Comment: I was editing the script while you were asking that question. Check it now. That should cover it.

Comment: I'm using C#... :-/ But I think I can make sense of it.

Comment: Thank you again! I will give this a try and let you know how it all works out.

Comment: Thanks again, Lucas!

Do you think I could add the IsActiveUser check to this script: https://www.screencast.com/t/M9y8DD2ufX

Comment: Well, add the check and if it is true, then I want to open the video modal - if it is false, I want to open the login/register modal.

Comment: Yes, you can add the login checker in there. Just be careful. If it's fully client side, expect people to bypass it.